# How to make Horizontal view scroller for Android Widget?

Tags: android, eclipse, android-layout, android-widget

Basically, I am making an `android` widget with views scrolling left to right and right to left, depending on the direction of a user swipe.

Below is my `mail.xml`. Can someone suggest me how to make a horizontal scroller? When I change this layout it says: `Problem loading widget`. Please suggest me a solution.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_margin="4dp"
android:background="@drawable/background"
android:gravity="center"
android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/widget1label"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/widget1txt"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />


</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think `HorizontalScrollView` is what you're looking for. Simply wrap the element you want to scroll and it should work.

Comment: Hi Thanks for your response actually I did that but it give me error on widget load as I mentioned above.What can be issue?

Comment: I tried this 
<HorizontalScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_margin="4dp"
    android:background="@drawable/background"
    android:gravity="center">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/widget1label"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/widget1txt"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"/>
</HorizontalScrollView>

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >
<TextView  
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:text="@string/heading_title"
    />

<ScrollView 
    android:id="@+id/layout" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"     
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"     
    android:scrollbars="horizontal|vertical" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"     
    android:layout_marginTop="5dip"     
    android:scrollbarStyle="outsideInset"
    android:fillViewport="true"> 

<HorizontalScrollView 
    android:id="@+id/horizontalView" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"     
    android:scrollbars="horizontal|vertical" 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"     
    android:layout_marginTop="5dip">



............Place all your layouts, views, such as linear layouts, table layouts, etc, that are needed for your app. Note that the TextView for heading/title (see above) will be outside the scrollview, so it will always stay visible at the top. Remove this if not needed, or add there more views as needed .............



    </HorizontalScrollView> 
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: Hi Abhi, I tried both solution but none of them is working.It says me 'Srcollview's liner parent is useless' while making layout in xml file.

Comment: hello Ali, see linear layout is working only in a single view. so made scrollview as a parent/root .. remove the layout code.

Comment: And check once, u have closed the layout tag or not??

Comment: I put  the scrollview to the root and then tested its giving error again When I launch app."Problem loading widget"

Answer (score 0):

So the answer is:Creating the App Widget layout is simple if you're familiar with Layouts. However, you must be aware that App Widget layouts are based on RemoteViews, which do not support every kind of layout or view widget.

A RemoteViews object (and, consequently, an App Widget) can support the following layout classes:

```
FrameLayout
LinearLayout
RelativeLayout
GridLayout
```

And the following widget classes:

```
AnalogClock
Button
Chronometer
ImageButton
ImageView
ProgressBar
TextView
ViewFlipper
ListView
GridView
StackView
AdapterViewFlipper
```